# Append date column to array imported from Gmail CSV File Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, csv, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I am trying to automatically import a daily report which is emailed from a third party system (on which I can't edit the values sent) to a google sheet to create a report over time.

The code below works and imports the data correctly, however the CSV file does not include the date which makes reporting imposssible.

I can get the date from the email and again this is working however I am unable to append this to the data written to the sheet. Ideally the code would add an extra entry to the start of each element of the array with a date.

```
/**
 * import CSV data directly from gmail attachments
 */
function importCSVFromGmail() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:Agent Performance report for newer_than:1d');

  // create empty array to hold data
  var allData = [];

  // get the threads that match this search
  threads.forEach(function(thread) {

    var messageCount = thread.getMessageCount();

    // get the messages in a thread
    var messages = thread.getMessages();

    messages.forEach(function(message) {

      var attachments = message.getAttachments();

      attachments.forEach(function(attachment) {

        // check attachment is CSV
        if (attachment.getContentType() === 'text/csv') {

          // extract the data
          var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString());
          var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(message.getDate()), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");

          allData = allData.concat(csvData);

        }
      });  
      Logger.log(allData);
    }); 
  });

  // paste into Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, allData.length, allData[0].length).setValues(allData);
}
```

Sample of CSV data

```
Agent,Tickets assigned,Tickets resolved,Tickets reopened,Tickets reassigned,First response SLA %,Resolution SLA %,FCR %,Private notes,Responses,Average 1st response time,Average response time,Average resolution time
Agent 1,1,2,,1,,100,100,,1,,,17:32:49
Agent 2,11,14,3,,88,86,67,3,15,06:09:35,04:04:20,19:44:18
Agent 3,18,25,7,,100,80,68,6,14,01:28:29,02:35:47,74:48:48
```

Expected Output would simply be the data in the CSV file with the date in the first column

```
DD/mm/yyyy,Agent,Tickets assigned,Tickets resolved,Tickets reopened,Tickets reassigned,First response SLA %,Resolution SLA %,FCR %,Private notes,Responses,Average 1st response time,Average response time,Average resolution time
DD/mm/yyyy,Agent 1,1,2,,1,,100,100,,1,,,17:32:49
DD/mm/yyyy,Agent 2,11,14,3,,88,86,67,3,15,06:09:35,04:04:20,19:44:18
DD/mm/yyyy,Agent 3,18,25,7,,100,80,68,6,14,01:28:29,02:35:47,74:48:48
```

Comment: Could you show expected output?

Comment: Sure thing, I have just added that. it would simply be the email date as the first column in the data. I'm not concerned that this would add a specific date to the header row as this will be filtered out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) [for each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) row:

```
const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString());
const date = Utilities.formatDate(message.getDate(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");
csvData.forEach(row => row.unshift(date));
```